# Json does not contain a definiton for 'stringify'?

Tags: c#, razor, json.net, jira-rest-api

I am trying to update a JIRA issue using Visual Studio 2015, Microsoft Razor, and C# with Json.Net 10.0.2. The code is:

```
public String updateJiraIssue(object objJira2) {
    JiraService.open("PUT", JiraUrl + "/rest/api/2/issue/NPI-24");
    JiraService.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    JiraService.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    JiraService.setRequestHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
    JiraService.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + GetEncodedCredentials());
    var myJSON = Json.stringify(JiraJson);
    JiraService.send(myJSON);
    String response = JiraService.responseText;
    JiraService.abort();
    return response;
}
```

The error occurs in:

```
var myJSON = Json.stringify(JiraJson);
```

The JSON is:

```
string jsonString = @"{""fields"":{""customfield_12302"":{""name"":""xyz""}}}";
```

Comment: Depends on your JSON, or possibly how you're interpreting it.  Where is your code?  What does your JSON look like?  Where do you see this error?  Please read [ask], and then [edit] your question to include some detail so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is a javascript function, which you would call from a web page script to serialize an object to JSON before making an ajax request.

In C#, there is a [`Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx) class in the `System.Web.Helpers` namespace, but its serialization method is called [`Encode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx), not `stringify`.  Note this class uses the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) internally to do its work; it does not depend on Json.Net.

If you want to use Json.Net, you should be calling [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) instead:

```
var myJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objJira2);
```